# How to get timestamp of photos using Photos framework?

Tags: ios, swift, photosframework

I want to retrieve timestamp of media that is stored in photo library on device. I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020254/get-timestamp-of-images-in-photo-library-using-alassetlibrary) but it for `ALAssetLibrary` that is deprecated in iOS 9.0+. I want to do so using `Photos` framework. Please help.

Comment: Please go through `PHAsset` creationDate and modificationDate. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/PHAsset/creationDate

Answer (score 2):

Here is the full answer:

```
let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Image, options: nil)

for i in 0..<assets.count {
    guard let asset = assets[i] as? PHAsset else {fatalError("Cannot cast as PHAsset")}

    print("creation date: \(asset.creationDate)")
}
```